# UIKeyboard does not hide when I touch outside the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I'm not figuering out a way to hide the keyboard when I touch outside the keyboard, is there any event that could hide the keyboard if I click outside the keyboard.
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

In the ViewController.m  write the touches began  method.In that method write the resignFirstResponder

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: This will interfere with the cursor handling of the text field.

Comment: one another problem, it does not work when I click on buttons

Comment: As I said this is not the answer, you are resigning the responder to any touch regardless of where or what type it is.

Comment: in the button action method write this [textField resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 8):

Here is a better solution that is gonna work for any UITextField in your view controller. You can even add it to your base view controller (if you have got one) and it will work like a charm.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: works great as long as you need it to dismiss on background, only

Comment: All UI work should be done on the main thread, including dismissing the keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to do that yourself. The normal approach is to place a transparent button over the screen (but below your text field) and then on the action for the button...

```
- (void)dismissPressed:(id)sender {
  [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I have multiple views over the screen it won't work perfectly thanks anyway found an answer use touches began

Comment: :) Ok.... but it won't be that simple... check what happens if you try to move the cursor in the text field...

Comment: is there any event for the UIKeyboard that touching outside the keyboard makes resigning first responder?

Comment: No, you will have to handle it yourself as per my answer. You *could* hook into the hittest method and check what is being touched and resign that way but there is no easy solution.